# Pandas - Print a single row in the same format as .head()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently formatting my data and I would like to print out a single row from the dataframe. So far I've tried this:

```
df.iloc[202]
```

However, I realized after testing my data the output doesn't ideally display how I would like it to show as I want it similar to the output style from `df.head()`.

My question therefore, is there a way to display a single row with the table style output in Pandas or not?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52813827/edit) to include an example of the output you want to see?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do it like this

```
df.head(202).tail(1)
```

I hope it will help you.

OR

And also you can use

```
df[206:207]
```

OR

df.iloc[[207]]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest solution, but does this do what you want to achieve?

```
df.head(202).tail(1)
```

or flexibel:

```
df.head(i).tail(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. My guess is you want to select just one row from your dataframe using `df.iloc[202]` but the output looks like this:

```
A    4
B    9
Name: 202, dtype: int64
```

While `df.head(1)` would look like this:

```
   A  B
0  4  9
```

You can get the *head()/table* style of the output by giving `iloc` a ***slice*** which includes *just the one row* you want:

```
df.iloc[202:203]

     A  B
202  4  9
```

The end of a slice is not included in the range and it doesn't throw an error if index 203 (or even 202) doesn't exist.